# Ruta hija no renderiza componente padre al hacer redirect en angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estoy intentando hacer el ruteo de mi aplicación, pero al momento de utilizar el redirect con *redirectTo* de *''* a *'home'*, no me renderiza el componente padre *PrivateComponent*, solo me renderiza el componente hijo, este es el archivo de rutas principal:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
 
  {
    path: '',
    component: PublicComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AlreadyLoggedGuard] },
    ]
  },

  {
    path: '',
    component: PrivateComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }, // **Aquí es donde hago el redirect**
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () => import("./_views/home/home.module").then(z => z.HomeModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'genres',
        loadChildren: () => import("./_views/genre/genre.module").then(z => z.GenreModule),
      },
    ]
  },

  { path: '**', component: Error400Component }
]
```

Y esta es la ruta del componente *home*:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Inicio'
    }
  }
]
```

Si redirecciona, pero solo muestra el componente hijo y no renderiza el componente padre, alguna idea de que es lo que podría estar haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

Tu segundo routing debería de ser:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    ],
  },
];
```

Si no funciona así tal vez existe algún problema al tener las rutas vacías.